# How to change only the image inside an imagebutton and not the whole imagebutton

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have an imagebutton which uses a btn_star. It looks like a small star on a grey button.

[image]

I want to change the star during runtime using the backgroundresource, but for some reason when I try to change it, it only changes the grey part and not the star part, so it looks like there are two stars ontop of eachother. Its the following command that I use.

> btnChild.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);

How do I change ONLY the star part in the imagebutton and keep the grey "button" part?

```
public void myClickHandler(View v) 
    {

        //reset all the listView items background colours before we set the clicked one..
        ListView lvItems = getListView();
        listposition = lvItems.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        state = lvItems.onSaveInstanceState();

        RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();

        TextView child = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(3); 
        ImageButton btnChild = (ImageButton)vwParentRow.getChildAt(9);


        Checkiffavorite();
        boolean favourite=false;
        for (String s : favourite_id){
            if (s.equals(child.getText().toString()))
                favourite=true;
        }   
        if (favourite)
        {
            btnChild.setSelected(false);
            DeleteFromDatabase(child.getText().toString());

            btnChild.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star);
            //ImageButton _Favorbtn1 = (ImageButton)btnChild.findViewById(R.id.BtnToClick);

        }
        else
        {
            btnChild.setSelected(true);
            AddToDatabase(child.getText().toString());
            btnChild.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
        }





        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);


    }
```

xml:

> ImageButton
>        android:id="@+id/BtnToClick"
>        android:layout_width="60dp"
>        android:layout_height="60dp"
>        android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
>        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
>       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>       android:focusable="true"

Best regards
Joe

Comment: Can you show us the XML code and Java part where you change your Button's background please?

Answer (score 1):

The method you use is for changing the background resource. To change the foreground, use the [`setImageResource(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) method:

```
btnChild.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modified answer**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"     
     />

public void myClickHandler(View v) 
    {
        if(flag==false)
        {
            flag=true;
            imgBtn.setSelected(false);
            imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        else
        {
            flag=false;
            imgBtn.setSelected(true);
            imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        }
    }
```

The above code is workable for me.

Comment: @joe please wait. I will check this and let you know.

Comment: @Joe I have find the problem and also give you the solve code.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The only thing that happens is that the button image disappears.
The btnChild.SetImageResource is inside a clickevent public void myClickHandler(View v) 
But I don't think it makes any difference. For some reason the btnChild.SetBackgroundResource works but it changes the background image.This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.
Tried it but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Joe can you please provide your XML and source code. Though I will log out now, but when I log in then I will inform you.

Comment: @Joe I have edited my code as per your code structure. It is workable for me. I don't know what happen with you. Please clear and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Use setImageDrawable to change ImageButton icon.
In Xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    />
```

In Java:

```
`ImageButton button = findViewById(R.id.button);


button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_star));
```